# Why does this method 'prove' a different inequality?

Tags: inequality

By using AM-GM twice and multiplying the results, we can easily show that

> If $a+b+c=1$ then $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} \geq 9 \tag 1$$

Now the method below also seems to be valid in each step, yet I cannot see the reason why this proves a different inequality!

$$a+\frac{1}{a}+b+\frac{1}{b}+c+\frac{1}{c} \geq 6\tag 2$$ since $x+\frac{1}{x} \geq 2$ for all $x>0$.

So $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} \geq 5\tag 3$$

I suspect it may have to do with the possibility of $a$, $b$ or $c$ possibly being negative, hence the method doesn't work since $x+\frac{1}{x} \geq 2$ only if $x>0$, but what if they were all positive quantities?

Comment: I have another inequality, as $a,b,c\leq 1$ then $\frac 1a , \frac 1 b, \frac 1 c\geq 1$ hence $$ \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} \geq 3\tag 4 $$

Comment: I'm not completely sure about the idea of both inequalities holding. For example, according to my third equation, the quantity $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$ could be 6 for example, as it is greater than 5. However, this contradicts $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} \geq 9$. This is my main issue with having two inequalities holding. My understanding is also that equality occurs at the minimum value of $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$ so wouldn't having two inequalities imply two minimal values?

Comment: @Trogdor, the main idea is that the inequalities $(1)$ and $(3)$ are both correct (because you **proved them** ) . This means that the LHS , the quantity $\frac 1a+\frac 1b+\frac1c$  is *always* greater than **both** $5$ and $9$. So for example the quantity  would never be $6$. or any number between $6$ and $9$.

Comment: If I proved that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} \geq 5$, then there must exist some $(a,b,c)$ such that equality occurs. In this case there is no such triplet, so surely there must be something wrong with the proof somewhere? A perfectly correct proof can not lead to an incorrect implication, can it? Another question I had about your response is "How would we know what the 'real' lower bound is?" Say I approached finding the minimum value of $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$ by using the method in equation 2. How would I know this yields a 'false' lower bound?

Comment: Note that if an inequality is true, it does not necessarily  imply equality must hold. For eg $2\ge1, x^2+y^2+1\ge 0$ are all perfectly valid. When an inequality is true and equality is also possible for some case, then you have found a best bound - min or max of the expression.

Answer (score 2):

You proved that $\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c \geq 5$, which is consistent with $\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c \geq 9$. You just didn't use an inequality that was strong enough. I could also say that $\frac1a > 0$, $\frac1b > 0$ , $\frac1c > 0$, since they are all positive. Thus proving $\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c > 0$.

If you use $x+\frac{1}{x}\geq2$, we have equality only if $x=1$. However we can't have $a=b=c=1$ because of the constraint $a+b+c=1$. Therefore the method doesn't work.

To actually solve it you can use the solution below. I've put it in a spoiler box if you didn't want to see it yet. Also this assumes $a,b,c>0$ but that is required.

> Use AM-HM: $$\frac13 = \frac{a+b+c}{3} > \frac{3}{\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c}$$ Therefore  $$\frac19 > \frac{1}{\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c}$$ Therefore  $$ \frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c > 9$$

Comment: And it's the best lower bound : take $a=b=c = \frac{1}{3}$ to achieve it

Comment: I don't see what do you mean by "To actually solve it", and the OP's question is very interesting , sometimes we all get inequalities which are not sharp enough , so I think you need to add **more explanation** then just providing another proof. (the op has already one). I don't understand either what do you mean by "You didn't use an inequality that was strong enough"

Comment: @Elaqqad I have provided the explaination in the first paragraph.